# what is the role of magic method in python?

Tags: python

Base on my understanding, magic methods such as `__str__` , `__next__`, `__setattr__` are built-in features in Python. They will automatically called when a instance object is created. It also plays a role of overridden. What else some important features of magic method do I omit or ignore?

Comment: Can you improve your question a bit more? More explanation would probably make it clearer.

Comment: What makes you think that magic methods are called automatically on object creation?

Comment: Check this out! Complete guide to magic methods http://farmdev.com/src/secrets/magicmethod/

Comment: @RahulLakhanpal that had about a tenth of them.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3  I rarely see programers call a a magic method outside of class. Thus, I guess that the magic methods run in the backend or background, or they are called since a instance object is initialized.

Comment: They don't run at all unless they're called, just like any other function or method.

Answer (score 4):

"magic" methods in python do specific things in specific contexts.

For example, to "override" the addition operator (+), you'd define a `__add__` method.  subtraction is `__sub__`, etc.

Other methods are called during object creation (`__new__`, `__init__`).  Other methods are used with specific language constructs (`__enter__`, `__exit__` and you might argue `__init__` and `__next__`).

Really, there's nothing *special* about magic methods other than they are guaranteed to be called by the language at specific times.  As the programmer, you're given the power to hook into structure and change the way an object behaves in those circumstances.

For a near complete summary, have a look at the python [data model](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html).

Answer (score 2):

There is a lot you can do with magic methods and since it can be hard finding the right way to get started, I'd like to give you some inspiration on what I'm using a lot.

While you're probably already using some of them (like `__init__`), I would start learning on the operator specific magic methods, which helped me a lot optimising classes and how I use them. The magic method `__mul__` for example allows you to describe what should happen to your class in case it's getting called by the multiplication operator. In the following example you can see, that the interpreter first looks for a multiplicand's `__mul__` method and if this doesn't exist (like in the second example) it tries to call the multiplier's `__rmul__` method.

**Example 1:**

```
class a:
    def __mul__(self, other):
        print("__mul__ a")

    def __rmul__(self, other):
        print("__rmul__ a")

class b:
    def __mul__(self, other):
        print("__mul__ b")

    def __rmul__(self, other):
        print("__rmul__ b")

ia = a()
ib = b()

ia * ib
# prints __mul__ a
```

**Example 2:**

```
class a:
    pass

class b:
    def __mul__(self, other):
        print("__mul__ b")

    def __rmul__(self, other):
        print("__rmul__ b")

ia = a()
ib = b()

ia * ib
# prints __rmul__ b
```

Any other operator works corresponding to this example. I hope that helps you getting started enhancing your magic method skills.

Answer (score 0):

hint:

To make your classes comparable you can use __cmp__.
The method is called with the two classes which are compared.
Return a positive value if the first class is bigger.
Return a nagative value if the second class is bigger.
Return zero if they have the same size.
You don't have to use the magic methods for every possibility.